# How to unpack dd file on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, dd

Is it possible to unpack files created with linux dd tool on Windows? 
I have tried that tool http://www.chrysocome.net/dd, but it crashes under Windows 7. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dd isn't a compression format, its a image creation application that saves to an uncompressed image format. One does not *unpack it* You can *write* it to a drive with dd, or *mount* it - on linux I'd use kpartx and on windows, something like [osfmount](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html) or [lmdisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk)
.

If you can mount it, you can probably simply image it over to a blank disk, or work on it directly

Comment: dd isn't even a format. it's a tool to create an exact bit for bit copy of something, and that could be *anything*, it's raw data

Comment: fixed it somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - You can use 7zip to extract the .img files then use windows to mount them directly.

Answer (score -2):

Finally I have found a tool, OSFMount, which allows to mount *.dd files as Windows virtual drives:
http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html
That is all I needed.

Comment: Thats mentioned as one option in my answer.